# Safarai Invalid redirecionamento para o whatssap

Tags: safari

Amigos o que deve fazer neste código para que ele redirecione o numero para o whatssap no iphone, quando clicado pelo safari ele é invalido mas no android funciona corretamente.

```
<li><a class='icon-fa-instagram' href="intent://send/+551799999999#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end"><i  style='font-size:60px;color:red;' />Whatssap Televendas</a>
```